# how to debug: if mpi can't run across machine

Tags: mpi, openmpi

I have around 20 servers,  I use mpi to distribute my task across servers, **all the server have the same version of OS (ubuntu 17.10), and all the package is installed with same scripts** (of course, I still can't guarantee all server are same)

**The problem is:**

**some of my servers can't be run together.  mpi print following output. I google around and have no idea how to debug this problem.**

Some people say that this is caused by I have different version of packages, software on different servers, but didn't say how to check which package.

Any suggestion will be very helpful.

- the command to check possible error.
- where can I find relevant logs

> ORTE was unable to reliably start one or more daemons. This usually is
>   caused by:
>
> - not finding the required libraries and/or binaries on one or more nodes. Please check your PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH   settings, or
>     configure OMPI with --enable-orterun-prefix-by-default
> - lack of authority to execute on one or more specified nodes.   Please verify your allocation and authorities.
> - the inability to write startup files into /tmp (--tmpdir/orte_tmpdir_base).   Please check with your sysadmin to
>     determine the correct location to use.
> - compilation of the sorted with dynamic libraries when static is required   (e.g., on Cray). Please check your configure cmd line and
>     consider using one of the contrib/platform definitions for your
>     system type.
> - an inability to create a connection back to mpirun due to a   lack of common network interfaces and/or no route found between them.
>     Please check network connectivity (including firewalls and network
>
>   ### routing requirements).
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------- ORTE does not know how to route a message to the specified daemon
>   located on the indicated node:
>
> my node:   roo-25   target node:  192.168.0.38
>
> This is usually an internal programming error that should be reported
>   to the developers. In the meantime, a workaround may be to set the MCA
>   param routed=direct on the command line or in your environment. We
>   apologize for the problem.

Comment: have you tried to `mpirun --mca routed direct ...` ?

Comment: It doesn't work. but It help me find solutions. I  google this command, I got a answer for a similar issue, it's solution is upgrade openmpi to  3.1.2. problem solved. I still have no idea how to debug this kind of problem.  So, thanks, at least I don't have to stuck at my work for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using mpi operators with kubernetes cluster ，you can debug with `kubectl apply -f xxx.yaml --verbose=6`, then you will get more detail information for this problem.
This is caused by multi machine communication, and suggest you to do build logging without password by using `ssh-copy-id role@machineip`, role means the the user who will execute the job, machineip means the destination to execute the job, for kubernetes cluster cluster i use root to do that.
And after that , I upgraded openmpi version from 4.0.0 to 4.1.2, it works.